# Imaging Centos system but avoid emergency mode after restore

Tags: centos, fstab

I'm using terabyte Imaging program to clone my drive but when I try restoring to another drive for another system it goes into emergency mode when booting up. If I comment out the `/dev/mapper` lines it boots up but causing problems with those missing. Any ideas on what I should change in the fstab file.

```
/dev/mapper/cs_root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=44088c0b-ce22-45f7-a635-f035cca1f317 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=5084-FAE6          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2
/dev/mapper/cs_home /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/cs_swap none                    swap    defaults        0 0
105.140.85.71:/home/data1  /mnt/data1 nfs defaults 0 0
```

ps. I put the extra lines in the fstab otherwise when I post it wraps all the lines.

Comment: when you clone your drive, are the UUID's cloned as well?